# Какой самый удобный способ переиспользовать компоненты в angular 7?

Tags: angular

Не так давно я начал изучать `angular` 7. Я раньше не писал на нём. Сейчас у меня есть ряд вопросов, которые мне важно знать, прежде чем я продолжу идти дальше.

Первый вопрос:
Я собираюсь создать два приложения (мобильная и для ПК). Эти приложения будут похожи друг на друга, за исключением того, что они будут иметь разные стили и HTML-разметки. Как лучше всего решить эту задачу не копируя компоненты?

Второй вопрос:
У меня есть приложение, которое использует много компонентов, сервисов и т. Д., И я хотел бы использовать эти компоненты (сервисы ...) в другом приложении, но я не хочу просто клонировать эти компоненты (потому что других приложений может быть много). Я хочу иметь возможность подключать необходимые компоненты в другие проекты, которые генерируются с помощью команды `ng generate application`, с возможностью замены файлов css. Как это возможно? В будущем тот или иной компонент может быть переписан, и я просто хочу внести изменения в одном месте.

Я буду очень рад, если вы дадите мне пенок в правильном направлении, где я мог бы найти ответы на свои вопросы.
Любая помощь будет оценена.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос очень сложный, так как с каждым годом сложность приложений всё растет, а лучших практик по оформлению структуры проектов ещё не выведено. Так происходит из-за того, что для мелких проектов тема неактуальна, а крупным, в полном погружении, мешает безнес составляющая. Ктому же, эта проблема не только `angular`, а проблема современного `frontend` в целом.

На данный момент есть только одно направление, которое ведет к решению -

1. создавать стили для компонентов используя css переменные и shadow-dom, с помощью которого можно будет задавать им значения на уровне выше.
2. хранить в приватных или локальных `npm` репозиториях.
3. пользоваться `storybook`.

К томуже, при оформлении сложных проектов, не забываем о введенной в `TypeScript` с версией `3.0`, такой возможности, как *ссылки на проекты*.

Comment: есть несколько вопросов: 1. каким образом задавать значения переменных для инкапсулированных стилей в `Shadow DOM`, к тому же зачем этот велосипед если angular поддерживает `Shadow DOM` из коробки для каждого изолированного компонента? 2. что именно вы собираетесь оформлять как `angular.module`? чем поможет в данном случае `storybook`?

Comment: 1. я описал обычный способ взаимодействия с shadow dow. 2. ui компоненты и сервисы. 3. облегчит разработку и работу с ui.

Comment: `angular.module` имеет непосредственное отношение к angular 1 :(

Comment: @overthesanity простите, вы к этому на основании чего пришли, поискового запроса в google? Да, если гуглить по фразе указанной мной, то действительно ссылки приведут на angularJS. Но мой ответ предназначен для разработчиков angular, которые сразу поймут о чем я говорю.

Comment: не поймут, потому что это разные концепции, к тому же в новом компиляторе angular `ivy` модули вовсе не используются, поэтому и задаю вопрос - чем поможет "оформление ui компонентов и сервисов как `angular.module`"?

Comment: @overthesanity 
> к тому же в новом компиляторе angular ivy модули вовсе не используются
Воистину! Удалю тогда пункт о модулях..

Comment: @overthesanity хочу уточнить, а если ngModule не использовать, то как инкапсулировать все внутренности компонентов, которыедо этого в приложение в видемодуля импортировались? Вместо ngModule зависимостирегистрировать в самомкомпоненте?

Comment: @OlmerDare, да, но компонентную архитектуру очень тяжело обезопасить от влияния изменений. Принцип единственной ответственности в SOLIDе проявляется в двух разных формах. В чистой компонентной архитектуре он превращается в CRP (common closure principle, что довольно таки тяжело поддерживать большими командами ), а на уровне полноценной модульной архитектуры — в принцип оси изменения, который позволяет создавать архитектурные границы.

Answer (score 0):

Можешь использовать [`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8) для расшаривания кода между проектами.